# How do I fix my addition for summing a specific row and column in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have all of my other methods that were required for my class program working properly, however I can not think of how to fix my row input and sum method and my column input and sum method. I also apologize for the ridiculously long method names, the methods for pre-named for the assignment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Two_D_Array_CMPS280_2016
{// begin class Two_D_Array_CMPS280_2016
   public static void main(String args[])
   {// begin main method

   int[][] brianArray = 
   {// initialize array and hard code values
      {1, 2, 3, 4},
      {5, 6, 7, 8},
      {9, 10, 11, 12},
      {13, 14, 15, 16}
   };// end array initialization   

   // Print segment to print values from methods for brianArray
   System.out.print("The sum of all elements is " + Total_2DArray_Elements(brianArray));
   System.out.print("\nThe average of all elements is " + Average_2DArray_Elements(brianArray));
   System.out.print("The sum is: " + Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Row_Number(brianArray));
   System.out.print("The sum is: " + Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Column_Number(brianArray));
   System.out.print("The largest value is: " + The_Largest_Value_In_Certain_Row_Number(brianArray));
   System.out.print("The largest value is: " + The_Largest_Value_In_Certain_Column_Number(brianArray));

   }// end main method
   public static void printArray(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin to print arrrays
       for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
           {
           System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " ");
           }
       System.out.println();   
       }
   }// end printArray method      

   public static int Total_2DArray_Elements(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array values
       int total = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
           {
           total += myArray[i][j];
           }
       }
   return total;
   }

   public static int Average_2DArray_Elements(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array values
       int total = 0;
       int average = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
           {
               total += myArray[i][j];
               average = total / 16;
           }
       }
       return average;

   }// end method to sum array values

   public static int Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Row_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array by user input row
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the row you would like to sum: ");
     int row = input.nextInt() - 1;
       for (int i = row; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[0].length; j++)
           {
           total += myArray[row][j];
           }

       }
       return total;   

   }// end method to sum array by user input row

   public static int Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Column_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array by user input column
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the column you would like to sum: ");
     int column = input.nextInt() - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
     {
        for (int j = column; j < myArray[0].length; j++)
        {
           total += myArray[i][column];
        }

     }
     return total;
   }// end method to sum array by user input column

   public static int The_Largest_Value_In_Certain_Row_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to return largest number by user input row
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int highestValue = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the row you would like the highest value from: ");
       int row = input.nextInt() - 1; 
       for (int i = row; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
           {
           if (myArray[row][j] > highestValue)
              highestValue = myArray[row][j];
           }
       }
       return highestValue;
   }// end method to return largest number by user input row

   public static int The_Largest_Value_In_Certain_Column_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to return largest number by user input column
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int highestValue = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the column you would like the highest value from: ");
       int column = input.nextInt() - 1; 
       for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = column; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
           {
               if (myArray[i][column] > highestValue)
                   highestValue = myArray[i][column];
           }
       }
       return highestValue;
   }// end method to return largest number by user input column

}// end class
```

Comment: When you are summing a row, or column you only need one loop.  You need two loops when you are traversing every row and every column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your methods to the following, should do you good :

```
public static int Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Row_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array by user input row
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the row you would like to sum: ");
     int row = input.nextInt() - 1;
           for (int j = 0; j < myArray[0].length; j++) {
              total += myArray[row][j];
           }
       return total;   
   }// end..
```

and

```
public static int Total_2DArray_Elements_by_Certain_Column_Number(int[][] myArray)
   {// begin method to sum array by user input column
   java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int total = 0;
   System.out.println("\nPlease enter the column you would like to sum: ");
     int column = input.nextInt() - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
           total += myArray[i][column];
        }
     return total;
   }// end m..
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was so close, but was unable to see exactly what I needed to do!

Comment: @simplest: welcome to stackoverflow. if an answer does what you asked for, please consider picking that answer as the right one and upvoteing all good answers..

Answer (score 1):

Here is **Java 8** magic, which will help u **sum**, **average** etc of any row or colum

```
    int[][] intArray = 
        {// initialize array and hard code values
           {1, 2, 3, 4},
           {5, 6, 7, 8},
           {9, 10, 11, 12},
           {13, 14, 15, 16}
        };

    //Sum specific column
    int columnNo=0;
    Integer sumOfColum=Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToInt(i->i[columnNo]).sum();
    Double avgOfColum=Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToInt(i->i[columnNo]).average().getAsDouble();
    System.out.println(sumOfColum);
    System.out.println(avgOfColum);

    //Sum of specific row
    int rowNo=0;
    Integer sumOfRow=Arrays.stream(intArray[rowNo]).sum();
    Double avgOfRow=Arrays.stream(intArray[rowNo]).average().getAsDouble();
    System.out.println(sumOfColum);
    System.out.println(avgOfRow);
```